# NSSavePanel getting warning: "please start panels using NSSavePanel rather than NSApplication or NSWindow"

Tags: macos, cocoa, nssavepanel

Running in macOS 10.15.6, built with Xcode 11.1, my app is suddenly (at least I just noticed) spitting out these warnings on the console when I present a save dialog:

```
WARNING: <NSSavePanel: 0x100e43250> found it necessary to prepare implicitly; please prepare panels using NSSavePanel rather than NSApplication or NSWindow.
WARNING: <NSSavePanel: 0x100e43250> found it necessary to start implicitly; please start panels using NSSavePanel rather than NSApplication or NSWindow.
WARNING: <NSSavePanel: 0x100e43250> running implicitly; please run panels using NSSavePanel rather than NSApplication.
```

The problem is, I *am* using `NSSavePanel` to present this dialog. Here's the entire method. I can't see what's wrong with it. I'm not using any deprecated methods. (In the case I'm having problems with, `window` is `nil`, so `runModel` gets called.)

```
/**  Present a modal dialog (window==nil) or begin a sheet (window!=nil) that prompts the user to create a new archive.
 *
 * Attaches the rundancy picker view to the save panel so the user can choose the redundancy level.
 * Presents a warning if the user picks a volume that has size limitations.
 * If successful, invokes the handler with the URL of the new repository and its creation settings.
 * @param window window for sheet, or nil for modal dialog
 * @param title optional title
 * @param name optional default name
 * @param directory optional default directory
 * @param handler completion handler
 */
+ (void)newArchivePrompForWindow:(nullable NSWindow *)window
                       withTitle:(nullable NSString*)title
                            name:(nullable NSString*)name
                     inDirectory:(nullable NSURL*)directory
               completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURL* repositoryURL, NSDictionary* settings))handler
{
    NSSavePanel* savePanel = [NSSavePanel savePanel];
    
    savePanel.title = ( title ?: @"New Archive" );
    savePanel.allowedFileTypes = @[kRepositoryFileType];
//  savePanel.canSelectHiddenExtension = YES;
    savePanel.extensionHidden = YES;
    savePanel.prompt = @"Create";
    savePanel.nameFieldLabel = @"Archive:";
    if (directory!=nil)
        savePanel.directoryURL = directory;     // set optional default folder
    if (name!=nil)
        savePanel.nameFieldStringValue = name;  // set optional name
    
    // attach the redundancy picker controller
    RepositoryPickRedundancyViewController* redundancyAccessoryController;
    redundancyAccessoryController = [[RepositoryPickRedundancyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RepositoryPickRedundancyView"
                                                                                             bundle:nil];
    [savePanel setAccessoryView:redundancyAccessoryController.view];
    redundancyAccessoryController.version = kDataRedundancyPickerSchemeDefault;
    redundancyAccessoryController.configurationIndex = kDataRedundancyPickerConfigIndexDefault;
    
    // Present the panel
    if (window!=nil)
        {
        // The dialog is attached to a window
        // Present a sheet attached to the window
        [savePanel beginSheetModalForWindow:window completionHandler:^(NSInteger result) {
            if (result==NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
                // User picked an archive: vet it and continue
                NewArchivePostProcessing(savePanel,window,redundancyAccessoryController,savePanel.URL,handler);
            else
                // canceled
                handler(nil,nil);
            }];
        }
    else
        {
        // No parent window: run a modal dialog
        if ([savePanel runModal]==NSModalResponseOK)
            // User picked an archive: vet it and continue
            NewArchivePostProcessing(savePanel,nil,redundancyAccessoryController,savePanel.URL,handler);
        else
            // canceled
            handler(nil,nil);
        }
}
```

Anyone have a clue as to what's going on here?

Comment: Hi, interesting, not sure if this might be of interest https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/655939

Comment: Saw that thread already; it didn't answer the question

Comment: I tried your code (without `RepositoryPickRedundancyViewController`) but I don't get the warnings.

Comment: You are correct, if I remove the `setAccessoryView` statement, the save dialog runs without logging any warnings. But this still shouldn't be happening.

Answer (score 2):

If you replace

```
if ([savePanel runModal]==NSModalResponseOK)
    ...
```

with

```
[savePanel beginWithCompletionHandler:^(NSModalResponse result) {
    if (result==NSFileHandlingPanelOKButton)
        ...
    }];
```

The message goes away.

I'm guess it's a subtle way of trying to encourage the use of more modern APIs.

The only problem is, the message is wrong, `runModal` isn't deprecated, and there's no mention or documentation of this anywhere. Which seems to be par for the course, these days. :(